# Is there a way to turn off foreign key constraints at database level?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We need to use existing sql to create a bunch of tables and this sql includes ALTER TABLE statements to add in foreign keys.  When we run this block of SQL, however, errors are thrown because tables needed for the foreign keys haven't been created yet (they are later on in the block of SQL).

Is there a way to turn off foreign key constraints at database level? (versus at table level)  We just need to create all of the tables and foreign keys and then turn it back on.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope - you cannot disable that at all. Stop looking for easy hacks. Typically you push the foreign key creation into the last step of schema construction to avoid this problems. A table with the appropriate primary (or unique) constraint must exist at the time a foreign key is created.

Answer (score -3):

To disable foreign key constraints when you want to truncate a table:

Use FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and remember to enable it when you’re done:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Or you can use DISABLE KEYS:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS;
```

Again, remember to enable if thereafter:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE KEYS;
```

Note that DISABLE KEYS does not work on InnoDB tables as it works properly for MyISAM.

```
Use ON DELETE SET NULL
```

If you don’t want to turn key checking on and off, you can permanently modify it to ON DELETE SET NULL:

```
--Delete the current foreign key first:

ALTER TABLE table_name1 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name1; 
ALTER TABLE table_name2 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name2;

--Then add the foreign key constraints back

ALTER TABLE table_name1 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (table2_id) 
        REFERENCES table2(id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE tablename2 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) 
        REFERENCES table1(id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; Seems to not work in SQL Server 2019.  Is this for MySQL?